# Android Stroke Around Material Button from Style

Tags: android, material-design

Trying to display an outlined button as described in the [material design docs](https://material.io/design/components/buttons.html#outlined-button). The best I can do results in a simple text button (text with transparent background and no border). What am I missing?

```
<style name="PrimaryOutlinedButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
    <item name="android:strokeColor">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:strokeWidth">4</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the sources I suppose that you should remove 'android:' qualifiers as the new material parameters were not available in the original styles.

See: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/res/values/styles.xml#L73

Comment: That's all it was. Thanks for the link. I should have traced that myself. I'll accept as soon as SO lets me.